# Send multiple files from angular typescript to spring and return as zip folder for downloading?

Tags: spring, typescript, zip

I want to send multiple files in an array to spring and create a zip folder for downloading

Comment: You'd have to share more details.. Do you want an ordinary upload?

Comment: I just want to zip multiple files available in client side using server side

Answer (score 0):

UploadController:

```
  @Autowired
  StorageService storageService;

  @PostMapping("/upload")
  public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFiles(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files) {
    String message = "";
    try {
      storageService.zip(files);

      message = "Uploaded the files successfully";
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      message = "Fail to upload files!";
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
    }
  }
```

StorageService

```
public void zip(MultipartFile[] files) {
    List<Path> filepaths = new ArrayList();
    for (MultipartFile file : files) {
        Path filepath = Paths.get("my/tmp/dir", file.getOriginalFilename());

        filepaths.add(filepath);

        try (OutputStream os = Files.newOutputStream(filepath)) {
            os.write(file.getBytes());
        }
    }

    File zip = new File("path/to/my/zip");
    try { zip.createNewFile(); }

    FileOutputStream output = null;
    try { output = new FileOutputStream(zip); }
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(output);

    try {
        for (Path filepath : filepaths) {
            File f = new File(filepath);
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(f);
            ZipEntry e = new ZipEntry(f.getName());
            out.putNextEntry(e);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while((length = input.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, length);
            }
            input.close();
        }          

        out.close();
        output.close();
    }
}
```